# service crashing on start

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

```
// PPS.java

package com.domain.Servicecrasher;
import android.app.Service;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;
public abstract class PPS extends Service
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate()
 {
  Toast toasty = Toast.makeText(PPS.this, "service created!", 500);
  toasty.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 200);
  toasty.show();
 };
 public void onDestroy()
 {
  Toast toasted = Toast.makeText(PPS.this, "service destroyed!", 500);
  toasted.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, -200);
  toasted.show();
 }; 
};
```

tried to call the service using two methods:

method 1.

```
{
 {
  {
   startService(new Intent(MainMenu.this, PPS.class));
  }
 }
}
```

method 2

```
{
 {
  {
  Intent startPPS = new Intent(MainMenu.this, PPS.class);
  startPPS.putExtra("com.domain.Servicecrasher.PPS", false);
  startService(startPPS);
  }
 }
}
```

these both return an error on the emulator saying the app quit unexpectedly and i click force close, but the main activity doesn't close, so i'm assuming it's the service that i am force closing. below is the DDMS output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.domain.Servicecrasher.PPS
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1929)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:985)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.domain.Servicecrasher.PPS
at java.lang.Class.newInstaceImp1(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstaceI(Class.java:1409)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:1926)
... 10 more
```

just a couple simple questions. 
what am i doing wrong?
what is the proper way to do this?

eventually i need the service to be capable of loading settings from a SQL base and continue recording audio to a file after the main activity loses focus or is closed.

for now i'd be happy if i could just launch a simple service.

Comment: What is "com.domain. **notlaunchingservice** .PPS"? We can't see that. Plus, if "com.domain. **Servicecrasher** .PPS" is the service you're trying to start then it's abstract and can't be created.

Comment: posted more logcat. notlaunchingservice was the old project name...now changed to Servicecrasher to reflect current hangup. sorry for the confusion. if i remove "abstract" i get a warning and it doesn't compile. i only included "abstract" because eclipse suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes, be they `Service`s or other things, cannot be instantiated.  Eclipse no doubt suggested that you add the `abstract` keyword to your class because you had not implemented all the necessary methods to make a concrete instance.

I don't know if Eclipse has an option like this (I assume it does), but IntelliJ IDEA has an option where you can select "implement methods" when you have an incomplete class and it'll add all the stubs you need to fill in.  Try that, or consult the documentation for a full list.

Comment: i forgot to import android.os.iBinder. works now! you're awesome dude! my first working service after two days of trying. thanks much!